# How to select default listbox by value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox, listboxitem

How to select the listbox Programmatic by  option value in vb.net. for Web Application

```
<select size="10" id="LstCatecoryTxt">
<option value="2265">Study Categories</option>
<option value="2331">Everyone</option>
</select>
```

I want to select 2331 value by vb.net coding wise
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Value As string  = "2331"
LstCatecoryTxt.SelectedValue=Value
```

The Above Uses you to select manually listbox by value